# how to increase performance in aws comprehend on custom classification

Tags: amazon-web-services, jobs, amazon-comprehend

I trained a custom classifier with simply two tag in CSV
I have feed my custom classification model with 1000 text each

but when I run a job in my custom classification model, the job take ~5 min (running) for analyses one new text, I search about this issue in AWS, but I don't find any answer...

How can I speed up / optimize my job for analysis new text with the model ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prior to Nov 2019, Comprehend only supported asynchronous inference for Custom classification. Asynchronous inference is optimized for bulk processing.

Comprehend has since launched real-time inference for Custom classification to satisfy the real-time needs of our customers. 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/comprehend/latest/dg/custom-sync.html

Note that Custom endpoints are charged by time units even when you're not actively using them. You can also look at the pricing document for details - https://aws.amazon.com/comprehend/pricing/